# How do i 'destroy all' a given Resource type in redux-saga?

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga

I'm new to Redux-Saga, so please assume very shaky foundational knowledge.

In Redux, I am able to define an action and a subsequent reducer to handle that action.  In my reducer, i can do just about whatever i want, such as 'delete all' of a specific state tree node, eg.

```
switch action.type
...
case 'DESTROY_ALL_ORDERS'
  return {
    ...state,
    orders: []
  }
```

However, it seems to me (after reading the docs), that reducers are defined by Saga, and you have access to them in the form of certain given CRUD verb prefixes with invocation post fixes. E.g.
`fetchStart`, `destroyStart`

My instinct is to use `destroyStart`, but the method accepts a model instance, not a collection, i.e. it only can destroy a given resource instance (in my case, one Order).

### TL;DR

1. Is there a `destroyStart` equivalent for a group of records at once?
2. If not, is there a way i can add custom behavior to the Saga created reducers?

What have a missed?  Feel free to be as mean as you want, I have no idea what i'm doing but when you are done roasting me do me a favor and point me in the right direction.

### EDIT:

To clarify, I'm not trying to delete records from my database.  I only want to clear the Redux store of all 'Order' Records.

Comment: Your understanding of the purpose of sagas is incorrect or insufficient. You can/should still clear your state in the reducer.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  A snippet would do wonders for me.

Comment: @ChadS. Is it correct to say that reducers are defined automagically via the Saga `createResource` function?  That's what is throwing me.  It's possible this is a quirk in the specific codebase I'm looking at, but there are no explicit reducers.  Or, would it be correct to say that Sagas are not related to reducers?  You are correct that my understanding is insufficient, this is why i need help.  Thank you in advance

Comment: Reducers are totally independent of sagas. I'm not sure why you're conflating the two. There is a library called `redux-saga-resources` that allows you to avoid some boilerplate stuff for CRUD reducers, and that library builds reducers for your resources for you. But if you're just using redux and redux-saga you'd write the reducers yourself. Either way the state is being cleared by the reducer. Either one you wrote, or one your library is providing for you.

Comment: After looking deeper into `redux-saga-resources` I believe the answer to your question`Is it correct to say that reducers are defined automagically via the [...] createResource function?` is yes. The documentation explains that the resource created by `createResource` has a `reducer` method that you pass to createStore as the reducer for the resource's state.
See: https://github.com/Zaibot/redux-saga-resources#readme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two key bit's of knowledge were gained here.

1. My team is using a library called [redux-api-resources](https://github.com/okbreathe/redux-api-resources#readme) which to some extent I was conflating with Saga.  This library was created by a former employee, and adds about as much complexity as it removes.  I would not recommend it. `DestroyStart` is provided by this library, and not specifically related to Saga.  However the answer for anyone using this library (redux-api-resources) is **no, there is no bulk destroy action.**
2. Reducers are created by Saga, as pointed out in the above comments by @Chad S..  The mistake in my thinking was that I believed I should somehow crack open this reducer and fill it with complex logic. The 'Saga' way to do this is to put logic in your [generator function](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial/), which is where you (can) define your control flow.  I make no claim that this is best practice, only that this is how I managed to get my code working.

I know very little about Saga and Redux in general, so please take these answers with a grain of salt.